# Separating my Java code into two methods

Tags: java

I want my main method to contain input values for a person’s weight and height and then for it to call for the bodyMassIndex method to get the health opinion (i.e. normal weight) which should then be output. Wondering if anyone could help me?

```
package bodymassindex;
import java.util.Scanner;

 public class BodyMassIndex {
 public static void main(String[] args) {

  double m; 
  double kg;   
  double bmi;

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

 System.out.println("Enter weight (KG): ");
 kg = input.nextDouble();

 System.out.println("Enter height (M): ");
 m = input.nextDouble();

 bmi = kg / (m*m);

 System.out.println("Your BMI is " + bmi);

 if (bmi < 16)
   System.out.println("Seriously underweight");
 else if (bmi >= 16 && bmi < 18)
   System.out.println("Underweight");
 else if (bmi >= 18 && bmi < 24)
   System.out.println("Normal weight");
 else if (bmi >= 24 && bmi < 29)
   System.out.println("Overweight");
 else if (bmi >= 29 && bmi < 35)
   System.out.println("Seriously overweight");
 else if (bmi >= 35 )
   System.out.println("Obese");
 }
}
```

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve here? If you give us a clear question, then we may be able to help

Comment: I'm asking how would I do what I have stated above..

Comment: Your code looks like it should work, care elaborating?

Comment: My code does work.. I want my main method to contain input values for a person’s weight and height and then for it to call for the bodyMassIndex method to get the health opinion (i.e. normal weight) which should then be output. How would I do this? Is my question.

Comment: You're working in Java, consider making BMI a class with weigh and height in the constructor. Then, make get methods for BMI and BMI class. Then, in your main, prompt the user, make a new instance of the class with the users inputs and call the getBMI and getBMIClass methods?

Answer (score 0):

This breaks it down into its own method, and create a method which passes in some test parameters. Also includes functionality to take in user input still.

```
package bodymassindex;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BodyMassIndex {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double m; 
        double kg;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter weight (KG): ");
        kg = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter height (M): ");
        m = input.nextDouble();

        bmi(kg, m);
        // bmiTest(); /* Uncomment to run some "test" values.*/
   }

   private static void bmiTest() {
       bmi(100, 2);
       bmi(50, 1.3);
       bmi(60, 1.8);
   }

   private static void bmi(double kg, double m) {
        double bmi = kg / (m*m);
        System.out.println("Your BMI is " + bmi);

        if (bmi < 16)
          System.out.println("Seriously underweight");
        else if (bmi >= 16 && bmi < 18)
          System.out.println("Underweight");
        else if (bmi >= 18 && bmi < 24)
          System.out.println("Normal weight");
        else if (bmi >= 24 && bmi < 29)
          System.out.println("Overweight");
        else if (bmi >= 29 && bmi < 35)
          System.out.println("Seriously overweight");
        else if (bmi >= 35 )
          System.out.println("Obese");
   }
}
```